# HighChart plots not displaying correctly on small div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, highcharts

I am using a javascript library called Highcharts https://www.highcharts.com/
to plot JSON data on a stock/line graph.

Reference the image below to get an understanding of the terms I am using in this post.
https://www.highcharts.com/images/docs/understanding_highstock.png

So everything works fine when clicking on the range selector buttons to zoom in. But when I use the navigator to specify a huge range (years), the final line plot is incorrect. I have created some images to help you understand what I mean.

Using the range selector buttons to specify a smaller range works perfectly when trying to plot `[1519162460000,246.39649367343821]` as my final price:

[image]

But now, let me resize the navigator in order to show the entire price history:

[image]

If you look carefully at the image you should be able to see that the last plot on the chart is incorrect and shows $230.72 when it should display $246.40 `246.39649367343821` <- rounded

As you can probably tell, this is a major issue for someone who is trying to display relevant price information on my website.

**If I do not restrict the width of the chart div or resize the browser window  the plots display fine but I still dont know the issue. (note: what I just described does not work in codepen because the viewport width is restricted so the plots mess up regardless when I navigate a big enough range)**

Below is a snippet of my js and html along with a link to the codepen I created.

**JS**

```
Highcharts.setOptions({
  lang: {
    thousandsSep: ","
  }
});



Highcharts.stockChart("chart", {
  chart: {
    width: 290,
    padding: [5, 5, 5, 5]
  },

  title: {
    text: "Litecoin Price" // make dynamic
  },

  series: [
    {
      name: "Price",
      data: JSON.parse(data)["stats"],
      tooltip: {
        valueDecimals: 2,
        valuePrefix: "$",
        valueSuffix: " USD"
      }
    }
  ],

  responsive: {
    rules: [
      {
        condition: {
          maxWidth: 500
        },
        chartOptions: {
          chart: {
            zoomType: "none"
          },
          credits: {
            enabled: false
          },
          scrollbar: {
            enabled: false
          } //,
          //navigator: {
          //enabled: false
          //},
          //rangeSelector: {
          //enabled: false
          //}
        }
      }
    ]
  },

  scrollbar: {
    liveRedraw: false
  },

  rangeSelector: {
    allButtonsEnabled: false,
    buttons: [
      {
        type: "month",
        count: 1,
        text: "1m"
      },
      {
        type: "month",
        count: 3,
        text: "3m"
      },
      {
        type: "month",
        count: 6,
        text: "6m"
      },
      {
        type: "year",
        count: 1,
        text: "1y"
      },
      {
        type: "ytd",
        count: 1,
        text: "YTD"
      }
    ],
    selected: 4,
    inputEnabled: true,
    enabled: true,
    inputStyle: {
      color: "#757575"
    },
    labelStyle: {
      color: "#757575"
    }
  }
});
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="card" style="padding: 10px; min-width: 330px;">
  <div class="card chart-card" style="height: 350px; overflow: hidden; width: 300px;">
    <div id="chart" style="height: 350px; min-width: 300px;">
                <div id="highcharts-loading">
                        <div style="display: block; margin: 0 auto; position: absolute; top: calc(50% - 24px); left: calc(50% - 24px);"><span class="loading1"></span></div>
                </div>

                <div id="highcharts-nodata" style="display:none; text-align: center;">No chart data found</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because when you zoom out enough, Highcharts groups the data and displays the average value. If you look at the tooltip it says "Week from Monday, Feb 19, 2018", which means the value that is being displayed is the average for that week. I believe there are some settings that allow you to disable that grouping, but at the expense of the graph interaction possibly becoming laggy due to rendering so many data points.

> Data grouping is the concept of sampling the data values into larger
>   blocks in order to ease readability and increase performance of the
>   JavaScript charts. Highstock by default applies data grouping when the
>   points become closer than a certain pixel value, determined by the
>   `groupPixelWidth` option.

The settings for data grouping on line charts are here: [series.line.dataGrouping](https://api.highcharts.com/highstock/series.line.dataGrouping)

Comment: I would like to try it out. I will have a look if I can find a way to disable it

Comment: can confirm. `dataGrouping: { enabled: false }` added to `series` fixed the issue